# Trying to connect a signal from another class to a slot in the main class

Tags: c++, qt

I needed a clickable QLabel, so I've created a class called "clickablelabel" which is a QLabel having the mouseReleaseEvent. Once that is called it will emit "clicked(cid)". "cid" is a public variable inside clickablelabel, set by clickablelabel.

When "clicked" is emit I want the UI in my main window changed, so I have done this:

*clickablelabel.h*

```
signals:
    void clicked(int id);
```

*clickablelabel.cpp*

```
void clickableLabel::mouseReleaseEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
{
    emit clicked(cid);
}
```

*mainwindow.h*

```
private slots:
    void test(int id);
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
void MainWindow::test(int id){
    qDebug() << id;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    connect(clickableLabel, SIGNAL(clicked(int)), this, SLOT(test(int)));
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

This is the error I am getting when I try to run the program:

```
"expected primary-expression before ',' token
 connect(clickableLabel, SIGNAL(clicked(int)), this, SLOT(test(int)));
                       ^"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the slot to a signal in an *instance* of a `clickableLabel`, not to the class itself.  In other words, construct a new instance of `clickableLabel`, maybe in your constructor, then pass a pointer to this object to the `connect` function.  Also, `MainWindow::test` should be a public slot I think; you have it declared as private.

Possible implementation:

In mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
    /*Your stuff*/
    clickableLabel* label = nullptr;
}
```

In mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) {
    label = new clickableLabel;
    connect(label, SIGNAL(clicked(int)), this, SLOT(test(int)));
}
```

Comment: Since MainWindow is the Class that creates the `connect()` function and owns the slot it's not needed to make `MainWindow::test` a public slot. Could you send me a sample code for creating the instance and passing a pointer to the object to the connect function? I've tried     `clickableLabel * clkLabel;
    clkLabel = new clickableLabel(5, this);  ` which makes the code compileable but `MainWindow::test` isn't called when the signal emits.

Comment: Make sure you have the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your `clickableLabel` definition.  Is `clickableLabel::mouseReleaseEvent` being called?  Also try running QMake and rebuilding your project.

Comment: `#define Q_OBJECT` in clickablelabel.h - Is that correct? the `mouseReleaseEvent` is called. When I try to use `connect()` from the clickableLabel class to call a slot in there it works too. I've tried your code now but it says _'nullptr' was not declared in this scope_.

Comment: `nullptr` is a c++11 feature, just use `NULL` instead if your compiler doesn't support it.  Anyway, that's probably not the problem.  Does the "Application Output" in Qt Creator show any errors/warnings?  Another thing to try is to store the result of the call to `connect`.  If it returns 0, the connection failed.

Comment: `NULL` is working. It says _no matching function for call to 'clickableLabel::clickableLabel()'_ now. I guess the arguments are needed? I've tried `label = new clickableLabel(-1, this);` which results in having 28 erros and 3 warnings caused by _'struct QObject::QPrivateSignal' is private_ after the warning _"Q_OBJECT" redefined". I've removed the `#define Q_OBJECT` from _clickablelabel.h_ - It's compiling without any errors now. `connect()` returns 1.  The signal gets emitted but the slot not called.

Comment: Don't put #define in front of the Q_OBJECT macro, just plain Q_OBJECT with NO semicolon afterward.

Comment: In the `class{}` or on top? On top gives me errors, in the class was it already all the time.

Comment: You put the `Q_OBJECT` in the class definition.  Any of the Qt examples that come with Creator will show how to do this.  Also make sure to run QMake and rebuild the project after doing this.

Comment: It was like that all the time. Also ran QMake and rebuilt the project. The slot is still not called.